# store characters in character pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a thread which parses incomming characters/bytes one by one.
I would like to store the sequence of bytes in a byte pointer, and in the end when the sequence of "\r\n" is found it should print the full message out.

```
unsigned char byte;
unsigned char *bytes = NULL;

while (true){              // thread which is running on the side
    byte = get();          // gets 1 byte from I/O
    bytes = byte;          //
    *bytes++;
    if (byte == 'x'){      // for now instead of "\r\n" i use the char 'x'
        printf( "Your message: %s", bytes);
        bytes = NULL;        //  or {0}?
    }
}
```

Comment: `bytes = byte;`....enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Did you allocate memory for `bytes`?

Comment: Do you use `C` or `C++`?

Comment: You can't store anything in a pointer, apart from the pointer itself. You can store things in memory pointed to by your pointer. That is where your program has a problem: your pointer points to `NULL`, or *nothing*. It needs to point to *something* before you can start reading or writing it.

Comment: In C++ don't use pointers to characters for string, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: Make bytes std::vector<unsigned char>.  You don't know how long the input is going to be.

Comment: This is going to sound mean, but.. have you read a C programming book? A pointer is just that: it points to a region of memory. here, bytes doesn't point to any memory, you need to allocate it first. then, to assign to the byte pointed to, you need to dereference the pointer as well, otherwise you overwrite the pointer value (memory address) instead: `*bytes = byte`. But seriously, read a C book.

Comment: some cast warning about integer to pointer, but can we focus on the principles of character pointers, i wish to understand this topic and do every simple things like these without going to post these very basic things on forums for help

,i am using C

Comment: If somebody has told you that arrays and pointers are equivalent, forget what they said immediately.

Comment: `*bytes++;` — why the `*`? (`++` has higher precedence)

Answer (score 1):

You should define `bytes` as array with size of max message length not a pointer.

```
unsigned char byte, i;
unsigned char arr[10];   // 10 for example
i=0;
while (true){              
    byte = get();          
    arr[i] = byte;       
    i++;
    if (byte == 'x'){      
        printf( "Your message: %s", arr);
    }
}
```

When you define `bytes` as a pointer, it points to nothing and writing to it may erase other data in your program, you can make it array or allocate space for it in run time using `malloc`

Comment: Your answer provides an alternative, which is not bad bay the way, but maybe the OP needs that pointer way. You could include an example with malloc.

Answer (score 0):

### Your Code

```
unsigned char byte;
unsigned char *bytes = NULL;

while (true){
```

Nothing *wrong* here, but some things must be cleared:

- 1. Did you **alloc memory** for your `bytes` buffer? That is, using `malloc()` family functions?
- 2. If so, did you *check* `malloc()` return and made sure the pointer is ok?
- 3. Did you include `stdbool.h` to use `true` and `false`?

Moving on...

```
byte = get();         
bytes = byte;          
*bytes++;
```

- 4. I'm *assuming* `get()` returns an `unsigned char`, since you didn't give the code.
- 5. **Problem**: `bytes = byte`. You're assigning an `unsigned char` to an `unsigned char *`. That's bad because `unsigned char *` is expecting a **memory address** (aka *pointer*) and you're giving it a *character* (which translates into *a really bad memory address*, cause you're giving addresses up to 255, which your program isn't allowed to access), and your compiler **certainly complained** about that assignment...
- 6. `*byte++` has two "problems" (not being really problems): *one*, you don't need the `*` (dereferencing) operator to just increment the *pointer reference*, you could've done `byte++`; *two*, it was **shorter and easier** to understand if you switched this line and the previous one (`bytes = byte`) to `*bytes++ = byte`. If you don't know what this statement does, I suggest reading up on [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and [assignment operators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_assignment_operators.htm).

Then we have...

```
if (byte == 'x'){      
    printf( "Your message: %s", bytes);
    bytes = NULL;      
}
```

- 7. `if`'s alright.
- 8. `printf()` is messed up because you've been **incrementing** your `bytes` pointer the whole time while you were `get()`ting those characters. This means that the current location pointed by `bytes` is the **end of your string** (or *message*). To correct this, you can do one of two things: *one*, have a counter on the number of bytes read and then use that to *decrement the `bytes` pointer* and get the correct address; or *two*, use a secondary *auxiliary pointer* (which I prefer, cause it's easier to understand).
- 9. `bytes = NULL`. **If you did** `malloc()` for your `bytes` buffer, here you're destroying that reference, because you're making an assignment that **effectively changes the address** to which the pointer *points to* to **NULL**. Anyway, what you need to clear that buffer is `memset()`. Read more about it in the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html).
- 10. Another *subtle* (but serious) problem is the **end of string** character, which you forgot to put in that string altogether. Without it, `printf()` will start printing really weired things *past your message* until a [Segmentation Fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) or the like happens. To do that, you can use your *already incremented* `bytes` pointer and do `*bytes = 0x0` or `*bytes = '\0'`. The *NULL terminating byte* is used in a string so that functions **know where** the string ends. Without it, it would be *really hard* to manipulate strings.

---

### Code

```
    unsigned char byte;
    unsigned char *bytes = NULL;
    unsigned char *bytes_aux;


    bytes = malloc(500);
    if (!bytes) return;
    bytes_aux = bytes;

    while (true) {  /* could use while(1)... */
        byte = get();
        *bytes++ = byte;
        if (byte == 'x') {
            *(bytes - 1) = 0x0;
            bytes = bytes_aux;
            printf("Your message: %s\n", bytes);
            memset(bytes, 0, 500);
        }
    }
```

- 11. `if ((*bytes++ = get()) == 'x')` is a compound version of the three `byte = get(); *bytes++ = byte; if (byte == 'x')`. Refer to that assignment link I told you about! This is a neat way of writing it and will make you look super cool at parties!
- 12. `*(bytes - 1) = 0x0;` The `-1` bit is to exclude the `x` character which was saved in the string. With one step we exclude the `x` **and** set the *NULL terminating byte*.
- 13. `bytes = bytes_aux;` This restores `bytes` default state - now it correctly points to the *beginning of the message*.
- 14. `memset(bytes, 0, 500)` The function I told you about to reset your string.
- 15. Using `memset` is not necessary in *this particular case*. Every loop repetition we're saving characters from the beginning of the `bytes` buffer forward. Then, we *set a NULL terminating byte* and restore it's original position, effectively *overwriting* all other data. The *NULL* byte will take care of preventing `printf()` from printing whatever lies after the end of the current message. So the `memset()` part can be skipped and precious CPU time saved!
- 16. Somewhere when you get out of that loop (if you do), remember to `free()` the `bytes` pointer! You don't want that [memory leaking...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)